# How to share a session in two web applications hosted at two different application servers?

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, payment-gateway

I am trying to interact with a payment gateway, where I want to share the session so that I can keep track of whether the user for which the payment was processed by the Payment Gateway is the one for whom request was made.

I would explain this below:

```
1. http://localhost:7080/requesterApp in WebSphere application server 1
2. http://localhost:8090/paymentApp in WebSphere application server 2
```

I am redirecting the user to the payment gateway via submitting a HTML form.

So now how do I make sure that the request made by user1 for payment from `http://localhost:7080/requesterApp` to `http://localhost:8090/paymentApp` 
 is processed for the same user?

Should this be handled via session?

Comment: Do they have shared access to a database?

Comment: Are these solutions homegrown?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really payment oriented, but rather an architectural one.
server1 needs to pass information to server2, and the communication needs to be done in the backend.
Assuming the two servers host different applications, than WebSphere session replication is not a solution. All you need to do is for the requesterApp to call the paymentApp in the backend and let it know that a user is coming its way. The communication can be made via HTTP or RMI or whatever technology you pick, as long as its secured (IP whitelisting).

so:

1. requesterApp notifies paymentApp that user "James Dean" is about to hit it's servers. all required parameters are passed at this point.
2. paymentApp stores the data at its end and returns a UUID token
3. requesterApp renders a form for the user, with the token embedded as hidden field
4. user submits the form and hits paymentApp
5. paymentApp retrieves the user data using the token. if needed, it may ensure it's the same user IP, cookies, etc.

Comment: When I am putting some values in session I do not get them back when a payment confirmation URL is returned by paymentApp.

Comment: not sure at what point in time you put them in the session, but it won't work. you need to store the variables in the paymentApp server, in your own storage, not a session (as the user didn't hit the server yet and his session isn't ready). A simple Singleton or db table would do.